# Ubuntu 16.04 lts server blocking admin pc

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server (ip 192.168.1.201) running on the lan and past an apt-get update, I cannot access it anymore from an admin pc (192.168.1.11). Server is visible to all other pcs connected on the lan.

What I have tried so far:

Checked the iptables to see if the ip of the admin pc is blocked using

```
sudo iptables -L -n --line | grep 192.168.1.11
```

Which returned an allow all

Checked the status of the firewall and checked for blocking rules - none

Applied a firewall rule to make certain that it allows the admin pc using

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.11
```

Rechecked the status of the firewall

As the problem persist I have done the following:

**Server:**

- Flushed the iptables
- Disabled the iptables
- Disabled the firewall

**Admin PC**

- Flushed DNS `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Disabled the NIC driver and installed a fresh intel driver
- Configured the IP

**Network Switch** - Cisco Catalyst

- Checked port status for error - no errors
- Restarted the switch

After all this, the problem persist where both server and admin pc cannot ping each other but both are able to ping all clients on the lan.

**Edit 1**

I changed the ip of the Admin PC to 192.168.1.200 and can ping and sync with the server

What can be the issue with the original IP of the Admin PC 192.168.1.11 ?

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot access" ? Can you ping the server from admin-pc ?

Comment: No I cannot ping the server from the Admin PC and neither can I ping the Admin PC from the server.

Comment: Can you ping anything from admin-pc ?

Comment: Yes I can ping the entire network from both the Server and the Admin PC

Comment: What if you ran 'arp 192.168.1.201' from the admin pc to get the mac address of the server? Can you explain how everything is hooked up? Like what pcs are plugged into what ports of what routers and switches you have? Do you have vlans on your network?

Comment: Please see Edit 1 I have temporary changed the IP of Admin PC and can ping the server. All pcs on the inner lan run on the same VLAN with fixed IPs, same applies for the server.